# Neutral Element on $(\mathbb{C},*,+)$

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I want to show the neutral Element on $$(\mathbb{C},*,+)$$

Let the complex Number be defined as:
$$(x,y)$$
Multiplication of complex numbers is defined as:
$$(x_{1}, y_{1}) * (x_{2}, y_{2}):= (x_{1}x_{2}-y_{1}y_{2}, x_{1}y_{2}+x_{2}y_{1})$$
By definition the neutral element is:
$$(e_{x}, e_{y}) *(x,y) = (x,y)$$
$$(x*e_{x}-y*e_{y}, x*e_{y}+y*e_{x})$$
This gives an equation system:
$$x = x*e_{x} -y*e_{y}$$
$$y = x*e_{y} +y*e_{x}$$

Is this the correct approach to finding the neutral Element?

If yes, what is the correct method for solving the equation system?

Comment: Of course you can determine the multplicative neutral element by solving the above equation system. But I am sure you already **know** that the neutral element is $(1,0)$, and in that case it suffices to verify the equation $(1,0) * (x,y) = (x,y)$.

Comment: I want to show how to get to the value (1,0)

Comment: Then simply note that you must have $(e_x,e_y) * (1,0) = (1,0)$. This gives you $1 = e_x$ and $0 = e_y$.

Comment: I don't see this being a good derivation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is
$$\mathrm{I}\quad x*e_x-y*e_y = x \quad|*x$$
$$\mathrm{II}\quad x*e_y+y*e_x = x \quad|*y$$
$$\mathrm{I+II} \quad x^2*e_x+y^2*e_x = x^2 + y^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \quad e_x * (x^2 + y^2) = x^2 + y^2 \quad | :(x^2 + y^2 )$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \quad e_x = 1$$
Putting the solution $e_x = 1 $ into $\mathrm{I}$
$$x*1-y *e_y = x \quad |-x$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \quad-y*e_y=0 \quad|:(-y)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \quad e_y=0 $$
Thus the neutral element is $(1,0)$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not (quite) correct because you should have $x=xe_x-ye_y$ and $y=xe_y+ye_x$ (just normal multiplication instead of your "*" operation). Also, the equations should hold for any x and y in $\mathbb{C}$ and this implies that $e_x=1$ and $e_y=0$

Comment: But how can I show it?

Comment: @Thomas Cristopher Davies :  Your mistake is that you are confusing “*” with the normal multiplication between two real numbers. Your operation is defined so that ($e_x,e_y$)(x,y)= ($e_xx-e_yy,e_xy+e_yx$) and NOT as  ($e_x,e_y$)(x,y)= ($e_x*x-e_y*y,e_x*y+e_y*x$). It wouldn’t even make sens for “*” to be defined in terms of itself...by the way, “*” is just complex multiplication

Comment: I would have used the correct dot if I had known that it is required. But you did not show how you derived the neutral element. I want to see how the equation system is being solved.

Comment: A neutral element is an element $(e_1, e_2)$ such that $(e_1, e_2)*(x,y)=(x,y)$ FOR ANY REAL x and y. Choosing for example $x=1,y=0$ yields $e_1=1,e_2=0$

Comment: I know the definition of a neutral element, but you did not show how you got to the neutral element. Well, don't bother, I will post tomorrow the solution